# Why is gh-pages option not available anymore?

Tags: git, github, github-pages

Few years ago I used to use a separate orphan branch `gh-pages` to publish my website. This was a good way to not pollute my branch with generated artifacts.

I noticed yesterday that the gh-pages option is not available anymore. Instead I have only these two options:

[image]

I did not find any documentation about that on GitHub so I ask my question here:

- Is it still possible to use an orphan branch to publish pages?
- Why this option was removed from GitHub? Was it a bad practice?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes it is possible to create a `gh-pages` branch, put your `index.html` (or what have you) there, push it to your GH remote, and the access your website. Once you do that, on your repo, there will be a tab with `Environment` where you will be able to access your deployment and see it. You don't even have to enable the `gh-pages` option in the GitHub settings menu!

While it is strange that this option is lacking in the settings menu, it is still available to use this functionality and is well documented [here](https://help.github.com/en/articles/configuring-a-publishing-source-for-github-pages).

What's even more interesting is that after I tested this and created my very simple GitHub page for one of my repos, the option TURNED ON in the settings menu and is available once you have such a branch :)

**Edit:**

<s>So this might be a bug with GitHub currently</s>

It looks like this is *not* a bug in GitHub, but rather they are moving towards *explicitly* managing GH Pages through a user-defined branch and a user-defined directory. [Their documentation](https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/github/working-with-github-pages/configuring-a-publishing-source-for-your-github-pages-site), namely steps 3 and 4, show that clearly.

---

Anyhow, carry on with your branches without worries!